# insert table inside div between two rows

Tags: jquery, html, css, dynamic, toggle

```
<div >
<table id="hidn">
   <tr>
       <td><label>Sl no.</label><input type="text" class="clear"/></td>
       <td> <label>name</label><input type="text" class="clear"/></td>
       <td><label>address</label><input type="text" class="clear"/></td>
   </tr>
 </table>
 <input type="button" value="add"/>
    <input type="button" id="buttonAwd" value="close"/>

<div>
<table id="tab" border="1">
<tr>
    <td>sl no.</td>
    <td>College</td>
    <td>address</td>
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td>NIT</td>
    <td>tripura</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="add student" id="button1" class="butnEvn"/>
    </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>NIIT</td>
    <td>delhi</td>
    <td><input type="button" value="add student" class="butnEvn" id="button3"/>
    </td>
 </tr>
    </table>

$(document).ready(function(){
$(".butnEvn").live( "click", function(){

  $("#hidn").slideDown("slow");
});

$("#buttonAwd").live( "click", function(){
$("#hidn").slideUp("slow",function(){
$(".clear").val('');
});
});
});
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/rQZX7/12/ check this link. I want to dynamically add that textbox values inside a div and place after each table row of main table which can be toggle and viewed. Please find a solution for me.

I have tried with index to insert new row for alternative row.

Answer (score 2):

I have added some id's to your tags. Use this code to append the data to table

```
$("#addToTable").click(function () {
    $("#tab")
        .append("<tr><td>" + $("#txtSl").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#txtname").val() + "</td>  <td>" + $("#txtAddr").val() + "</td><td>" + "<input type='button' value='add student'  class='butnEvn'/></td></tr>");
});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rQZX7/15/)

**Edit**

```
var obj;
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".butnEvn").live("click", function () {
        obj = this;
        $("#hidn").slideDown("slow");
    });

    $("#buttonAwd").live("click", function () {
        $("#hidn").slideUp("slow", function () {
            $(".clear").val('');
        });
    });
});

$("#addToTable").click(function () {
    $(obj)
        .parent()
        .parent()
        .after("<tr><td>" + $("#txtSl").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#txtname").val() + "</td><td>" + $("#txtAddr").val() + "</td><td>" + "<input type='button'   value='add student'  class='butnEvn'/></td></tr>");
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rQZX7/18/)

Comment: thanks for your reply but it should append under the calling row and should be wrapped inside div

Answer (score 1):

Give id :  `<td> <label>`name`</label><input type="text" class="clear" id="name"/></td>`
`<td><label>`address`</label><input type="text" class="clear" id="addr"/></td>`
`<input type="button" value="add" id="add"/>`

Add this code into javascript :

```
$("#add").live("click",function(){
   var num=$(".clear").val();
   var name=$("#name").val();
    var addr=$("#addr").val();
    $('#tab').append('<tr><td>'+num+'</td><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+addr+'</td><td><input type="button" value="add student" id="button1" class="butnEvn"/></td></tr>');

$(".clear").val('');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add ids for the textboxes and try the following code

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
        var slNo;
        $(".butnEvn").on( "click", function(){  
            slNo=$(this).parents("tr");         
        });
        $("#buttonAwd").on("click",function(){          
                $("#hidn").hide();      
        });

    $("#add").on( "click", function(){      
        var address=$("#address").val();
        var name=$("#name").val();
        var slno=$("#slno").val();
        var html='<tr><td>'+slno+'</td><td>'+name+'</td><td>'+address+'</td><td><input type="button" value="add student"  class="butnEvn"/></td></tr>';     
        if(slNo==undefined){            
            $("#tab").append(html);
        }
        else{
        $(html).insertAfter(slNo);
        }
    });
});
```